# Какие типы изображений поддерживает iText?

Tags: javascript, java, .net, pdf, itext

Я хочу добавить PNG-изображение в PDF-файл, но я знаю, что PDF не поддерживает PNG-файлы. Значит ли это, что я не могу использовать PNG-файлы в iText?

Answer (score 0):

iText поддерживает изображения форматов JPEG, JPEG2000, GIF, PNG, BMP, WMF, TIFF, CCITT и JBIG2. Это не значит, что эти типы изображений также поддерживаются в PDF. Если определенный тип изображения (например, PNG) не поддерживается в PDF, iText конвертирует его в тот тип изображения, который определен в спецификации PDF.

•   Изображения формата JPEG хранятся в iText в исходном виде. Можно взять потоковое содержимое Image XObject формата JPEG, скопировать его в файл, и у вас получится правильное изображение в формате JPEG. Следующий фильтр позволяет распознать эти изображения: `/DCTDecode`.

•   Формат JPEG2000 поддерживается с версии PDF 1.5. Название фильтра — `JPXDecode`.

•   PDF поддерживает изображения со сжатием LZW (оно используется для GIF-изображений), но iText декодирует GIF-изображения в изображения RAW. Если создать `Image` с помощью iText и указать путь к GIF-файлу, то в PDF-файле получится изображение с фильтром `/FlateDecode`.

•   Изображения в формате PNG не поддерживаются в PDF-файлах, поэтому iText декодирует PNG-изображения в RW. Если пространство цветов изображения DeviceGray и имеет 1 бит на компонент, то будут использованы метод сжатия CCITT и фильтр `/CCITTFaxDecode`. В обратном случае будет использован фильтр `/FlateDecode`.

•   BMP-файлы хранятся в группе сжатых пикселей с использованием фильтра `/FlateDecode`.

•   С форматом WMF ситуация особая. Если вставить WMF-файл в PDF-документ с помощью iText, то iText конвертирует изображение в синтаксис PDF. iText создаст объект Form XObject вместо добавления Image XObject.

•   Когда данные изображения кодируются с использованием факсимильного стандарта CCITT, используется фильтр `/CCITTFaxDecode`. Это обычно монохромные изображения с одним битом на пиксель.

•   Помимо этого, в iText могут обрабатываться TIFF-файлы. В зависимости от параметров TIFF-файлов iText решает использовать `/CCITTFaxDecode`, `/FlateDecode` или даже `/DCTDecode` в качестве фильтра.

•   Для JBIG2 используется фильтр `/JBIG2Decode`.

Обычно с форматом изображений сложности не возникают. Класс `Image` сам выбирает правильный метод сжатия.
Дополнительная информация. PDF-файлы поддерживают прозрачность, однако стоит помнить, что прозрачные изображения не поддерживаются в PDF. Одно изображение, содержащее прозрачные области, может быть конвертировано в два разных изображения.

1. Непрозрачное изображение.
2. Маска изображения.
   Все это происходит в самом PDF-файле. Если добавить прозрачное изображение в PDF-файл, то его нельзя будет оттуда экспортировать. Придется выгружать два изображения: непрозрачную версию и маску.